# Do I need a controller for any routes in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, static, embedded-ruby

I am implementing an html template for a Contact us page in my app. I am wondering if I can somehow  pass a link  for that page, which will have no behaviour,  without having to generate a new controller which seems to be not possible. I tried to place the template in the public folder and then pass a link to /public/contact, being the template contact.html.erb,  but rails returns a uninitialised controller routing error.

here is what I have set in the routes.rb file

> get 'public/contact'

and this is the application.html.erb that carries my link to that

```
   </div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/info/news">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/info/faq">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/public/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice that we have also the path info/news and info/faq

I had generated a controller info to handle all these static pages. I would just like to know if this a good practice or should I use other drier way to implement this?

Comment: Every view will have it's controller which consists of the actions it will perform , it doesn't matter if it's a static page ot dynamic but a controller is always assigned to the page and is a good practice too . As requirements change over time , and you never know one might tell you to put captcha in your contact form :)

Comment: see https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a good approach to have a controller for your static pages as well, you can actually generate a controller for **pages** to handle the **static pages** like about, contact e.t.c  rails generate controller pages contact about

you would just access that in
    localhost:3000/pages/contact

Then your view would be in **app/views/pages/contact.html.erb**

routes.rb
get "pages/contact"
get "pages/about"

Answer (score 0):

wHY do you need to generate a new controller just for a request.Recommended way is to just add a new action in your common/utility controller with a get request to show about us.
 for example: `match '/about' => 'pages#about'` 
This is good as you can cache the page to **boost performance** as well you can make it **dynamic(html.erb)**

**OR**

Assuming that the static file(only html) is in `public` folder,**ADD** an anchor tag directly to open it in new page using `target=_blank` attribute.

```
<%= link_to "About Us", "/about_us.html" ,:target=>"_blank"%>
```